# Forçar refresh do aplicativo Gallery no Android 4.4

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo que manipula imagens, nele tem opções de mover e deletar imagens, quando deleto uma imagem é enviado um boradcast para que o aplicativo gallery do android reconheça que a imagem não está mais ali. Está funcionando perfeitamente, com exceção do Android 4.4!

Estou usando assim:

```
public void forceMediaScan(String path){
        File f1 = new File(path);
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(f1));
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
}
```

Já pesquisei e tentei usar o scanFile, mas não funciona, o aplicativo Gallery do Android 4.4 não reconhece a alteração

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{path}, null,null);
```

Já tentei usar o scanFile para um arquivo especifico e para um path inteiro (que é o caso do exemplo), mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a resposta, foi falta de atenção minha.
o media scan não aceita um folder como path, tem que por imagem por imagem em um vetor de String, para só assim usar o scanFile.

dentro do for onde percorre a pasta:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{aFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null,null);
```

Note que usei getAbsolutePath() para poder pegar o caminho completo.

Não usem o sendBoradcast para esta finalidade!
scanFile serve para isto, e é muito mais rápido neste caso.